# Characters' Shirt Texture Deforming Strangely

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I tried posting this on the Unity forums but no one there knows what the problem is and they suggested it could be a UV mapping problem within Blender. When exported my character from Blender into Unity via fbx, I've been trying to figure out why his shirt texture is stretching only in certain areas and I cannot figure it out. Here's a link to a video so you can see the problem:

(https://mega.nz/#!y51X1YJJ!yNT7cQiRN80-u2hBvdOpSyjATwV2_xc4jmvj8XVjw0QI).

I think I'll try to see if weight painting is causing the problem a little later today. I've already tried all the following things:

**Tried in Blender:**

Applied location rotation and scale before export.
Applied all modifers before export except armature modifer.
Tried UV minimize stretch.
Tried conformal UV unwrap.
Tried changing Auto Texture Space on the shirt and changing it to the same rotation, location, and scale of the object.

**Tried in Unity:**

Texture Type: Normal Map
Wrap Mode: Repeat

If you any ideas, please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem and it was simpler than I thought it would be. The reason for this strange deformation on the texture of the shirt wasn’t due to any of the reasons above. It was because I hadn’t noticed that if I change the angle of the camera view in Unity, I would see that there’s a serious weight paint problem in the shoulder area which I already know how to fix. This problem doesn’t show up in Blender because of the differences in how Unity and Blender process the visuals of weight painting. I thought I share this in case anyone else is having a similar problem and can’t figure it out. Make sure to change the angle of the camera to make sure what you’re seeing is actually what you think you’re seeing.

[image]